# Getting number of previous versions of a remote volume from powershell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, previous-versions

I am running Windows server 2019 Standard, powershell version 5.1.17763.316.
I have a remote volume, and by right-click -> properties -> previous versions, I get this:

[image]

I would like to check how many previous versions the volume has from powershell, because I need it as a part of an automation.

Stuff I tried and did not work:

1. `volrest` - gets `The term 'volrest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`
2. `vssadmin list shadows /for=\\10.2.10.49\v1` - gets `No items found that satisfy the query.`
3. Mapping the volume to `K:` and then `vssadmin list shadows /for=K:` - gets `Error: Either the specified volume was not found or it is not a local volume.`

How can I achieve this?